# How to obtain normalised ECG given ECG readings across lead 1, 2, and 3?

Tags: physiology, cardiology, human-physiology, electrophysiology, electrocardiography

I saw this youtube video on ECG readings and cardiac dipole vector locus of the heart across the three leads. Posting screenshots from it:

[image]

[image]

My question is how to obtain the graph (2nd image) from the 3 graphs in the first image? Should I simply add them or is there something more to it?

---

link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H8jVRhQkRjg